# Python reference error when running function in a function

Tags: python, function, tkinter

I am trying to create a binomial expansion calculator using tkinter in one of my first coding projects.
I have received integer values from the user inputs for a, b and n (for the form a + b^n) am trying to work on the a term first.

For this I am trying to print out a^n, a^(n-1), a^(n-2) etc until I get a^0. I have done this in the function ExpandA within the function expansion.

However when I run the code I get the error: local variable 'IntN' referenced before assignment. I am not sure as to why.

I don't think I can all ExpandA within expansion since I am using the command function to run my variable in tkinter.

I would be grateful if anyone could help (sorry if the coding is bad, I'm trying to start out)!

```
python
#Creating the functions
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

def expansion():
    IntA = int(entry_a.get())
    IntB = int(entry_b.get())
    global IntN
    IntN = int(entry_n.get())
    print(IntN)

    global ExpandA
    def ExpandA():
        for IntN in range (IntN,0,-1):
            print(IntA**IntN)

#Calling the function
button = Button(root, text = "Calculate", command = expansion)
```

Error: local variable 'IntN' referenced before assignment

Comment: The backtrace should tell you exactly what line the error is coming from. Also, your for-loop syntax is confusing — IntN seems to be declared both as a global and also as a local variable of iteration, which could cause some unexpected behavior.

Comment: You assign a value to `IntN` via the for loop in ExpandA, so python flags it as a local variable. But you try to read it when you call `range()` before you actually assign a value to it. You could declare it global in ExpandA if you want the loop value to be visible outside, or you could use a different loop variable in ExpandA.

Comment: its highly recommended to take object oriented programming paradigm for working with tkinter. This case, no need to assign variables globally that cause so much confusion and bugs. https://python-textbok.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/Introduction_to_GUI_Programming.html

Comment: Thank you! I realise my confusion of declaring the variable in my for loop now, and have changed the variable name, and now my code works! : )